# Qual framework ou ferramenta posso utilizar para gerar relatórios?

Tags: java

Tenho uma dúvida quanto a geração de relatórios em Java:

No meu caso preciso de uma ferramenta para gerar relatórios diários que possam ser impressos ou exportados.

Qual framework ou ferramenta vocês podem me indicar?

Comment: Cara eu te indicaria JasperReports, mas também te indicaria que você reformulasse sua pergunta, tentando deixa-la um pouco mais completa

Comment: R.Santos tudo bem?

Comment: Teoricamente qualquer string pode ser exportada e qualquer tipo de documento (.docx, .pdf, .html) pode ser impresso. Você precisa descrever melhor o que você quer.

Comment: Eu uso eclipse e estou começando a estudar spring.

Comment: Além disso, o que é que o seu problema tem a ver com Spring? Você colocou Spring no título, mas o corpo da pergunta nada tem a ver com Spring.

Comment: O sistema no qual eu vou desenvolver, precisa gerar relatorios e exportar para excel e isso pode ser por extensao csv, ou em pdf.

Comment: Bom em cima dessas "Vastas informações" a resposta do @KaranAlvesPereira já resolve sua questão

Comment: o sistema vai ser desenvolvido com o framework spring e por isso mencionei ok Victor Stafusa. Sou novato em java, fiz um curso mas nao cheguei a desenvolver uma aplicaçao mais madura ok

Comment: obrigado a todos pela sugestoes e dicas.

Answer (score 3):

O que normalmente é utilizado para geração de relatórios em java é o [Jasper](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library). Já trabalhei também com o [Crystal](http://www.crystalreports.com/crystal-viewer/) (não recomendo). As duas ferramentas possuem a opção de imprimir ou exportar os arquivos.

Answer (score 0):

Existe um projeto chamado BIRT Report. 
http://www.eclipse.org/birt/